# RSpec: get list of all examples that will be run

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I am using RSpec 3.

In a `before(:suite)` block want to get a (nested?) list of all examples that will be run in the current spec run (i.e. when a path is given) so I can scan through all their metatdata.

Background: I hope to be able to deduct whether capybara specs are present and start a frontend server if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to do it upfront, [`when_first_matching_example_defined` hook](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/when-first-matching-example-defined-hook) will run the code specified

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.when_first_matching_example_defined(:capybara) do
    start_server
  end
end
```

```rb
RSpec.describe do
  describe 'non-capybara' do
    # when running this example group only, `start_server` won't be called
  end

  describe 'capybara', :capybara do
    # when RSpec gets to this example group, it will call `start_server`
  end
end
```